# Error while compiling the xamarin.android document

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've installed API 's needed for xamarin.
Bt after that an error saying System.objectModel could not be found. I also add it from references. Then the mattetr is solved but now when I hot run in Visual Studio the program starts to compile and it also starts the emulator. But no longer result. visual studio displays that `emulatoris not ready` or `cannot find or load main class sun.security.tools.keytool`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like the installation is not complete. Please check if everything, including the prerequisites are installed correctly. Did you install the right Java JDK version?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis problem solved brother. thanks